# Как подключать файлы к проекту,после сборки с помощью webpack, если в названии прописывается hash?

Tags: php, javascript, webpack, twig

Задача при каждой сборки бандлов с помощью `webpack`, дописывать в названия бандлов со стилями и `js` хэш.Собственно говоря, сделать это не сложно. В конфиге надо просто прописать что-то типа:

```
output: {
        filename: '[name]-[hash:6].min.js',
        path: BUILD_DIR + '/js'
    },


new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "../css/style-[hash:6].min.css",
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        }),
```

Но возникает проблема. В проекте эти бандлы подключаются в `twig` и там я указываю путь и название файла. Без хеша как мы видим style.min.css и в head шаблона я пишу `"assets/css/style.min.css"` Теперь же webpack получается, каждый раз генерирует новые имена, например `style-b826d0.min.css`, добавляетв  название хеш. И разумеется стили не подтягиваются. По сути надо каждый раз менять имя файла, т.к. хеш будет меняться. Как решить данную проблему, чтобы новый бандл с новым именем автоматически подтягивался в проект??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, ларчик просто открывался. в Твиге можно подборосить html-ку
[вот так](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html)
Также надо использовать вебпаковский `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, указываем пути и направялем `html`  в папку с твигом, куда мы будем его инклудить(почему-то если их арсположить отдельно, `twig` ругается). Ну а дальше, если пути к `js`  и `css` бандлов заданы верно, то вебпак подставит бандлы с хешем в названии как надо. В моем случае я генерировал html  на основе существующего `html-шаблона`,но можно это сделатьи  без шаблона

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: ' My title ',
            template: './templates/index.html',
            filename: '../../tiwg_template/index.html'
        }),
```